# Fibonacci's rabbits variation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion, fibonacci-numbers

In this variation on Fibonacci rabbits the growth of mature rabbits in a period has to be less than 10%.

1. After one period the rabbits are called "young rabbits", after two periods the rabbits will be mature rabbits.
2. Each pair of mature rabbits will give birth to a pair of newborn rabbits.
3. Only 80% of the rabbits survive at birth.
4. After the mature rabbits gave birth, hunters have to kill $p \cdot 100$% of the rabbits such that the growth of mature rabbits in a period is less than 10%.

What must the value $p$ at least be to meet this criterium? Can I solve this using a recurrence relation just like in the normal version of Fibonacci's rabbits?

Comment: Do they kill $p.100\%$ of the mature rabbits or $p.100\%$ of all rabbits?

Comment: @tomi they kill only the mature rabbits

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, if there are $m_0$ mature rabbits and $y_0$ rabbits at time $0$, then $y_1=.8m_0$ and $m_1 =  \frac{100-p}{100}m_0+y_0< 1.1m_0$  Correct?

Comment: @saulspatz if $y_0$ are the amount of young rabbits at time 0, then I am not sure if $y_1 = .8m_0$, since the rabbits are newborn first, then they become young rabbits and then they become mature rabbits.

Answer (score 1):

As [tomi](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/215986/tomi)—whose notation I shall adopt—shows in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3566825/fibonaccis-rabbits-variation/3567171#3567171),
$$
y_{n+1}=0.8x_n\ ,
$$
and
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}&=(1-p)x_n+y_n\\
&=(1-p)x_n + 0.8x_{n-1}\ .
\end{align}
The solution of this recurrence relation is given by
$$
x_n= \left(\frac{x_1-\lambda_-x_0}{\lambda_+-\lambda_-} \right)\lambda_+^n- \left(\frac{x_1-\lambda_+x_0}{\lambda_+-\lambda_-} \right)\lambda_-^n\ ,
$$
where
$$
\lambda_\pm=\frac{1-p\pm\sqrt{(1-p)^2+3.2}}{2}\ .
$$
Since $\ -1<\lambda_- < 0\ $, the term $\ \left(\frac{x_1-\lambda_+x_0}{\lambda_+-\lambda_-} \right)\lambda_-^n\ $ in the expression for $\ x_n\ $ oscillates between positive and negative values of ever decreasing magnitude which converges to $0$ as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $.  The asymptotic growth rate of the population per period (or the constant *actual* growth rate, if $\ x_1=\lambda_+x_0\ $) is therefore $\ \lambda_+\ $, which is required to be less than $\ 1.1\ $. That is
\begin{align}
&&\frac{1-p+\sqrt{(1-p)^2+3.2}}{2}<1.1\\
&\iff&\sqrt{(1-p)^2+3.2}<p+1.2\\
&\iff& (1-p)^2+3.2<(p+1.2)^2\\
&\iff& \frac{69}{110}< p\ .
\end{align}

Comment: I think you have made a mistake. I said that $y_{n+1}=0.8z_n$. This means that $y_{n+1}=0.8x_{n-1}$.

Comment: What I missed is that you've put $\ z_{n+1}=x_n\ $, which I believe is incorrect.   The newborns produced by the adults appear *immediatelty*, not after a delay of one time period—that is, $\  z_n=x_n\ $.  This, at least, is what happens in Fibonacci's original problem, where the term $\ x_{n-1}\ $ in the recurrence $\ x_{n+1}=x_n+x_{n-1}\ $ represents the number of rabbits born at time $\ n-1\ $ and reaching maturity at time $\ n+1\ $.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It's tricky to know what exactly is intended by the questioner. I agree that your interpretation fits better with the original Fibonacci problem, and I'll adapt my answer accordingly.

Comment: ... and now our answers agree!

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_n$ be the number of mature rabbits at time $n$.

Let $y_n$ be the number of young rabbits at time $n$.

Let $z_n$ be the number of newborn rabbits at time $n$.

The number of newborn rabbits is equal to the number of mature rabbits, so $z_{n}=x_n$

80% of newborn rabbits survive to become young rabbits. This is equivalent to $y_{n+1}=0.8z_n$

With no intervention from hunters, all young rabbits would become mature rabbits and all mature rabbits would stay alive as mature rabbits. This is equivalent to $x_{n+1}=x_n+y_n$

Killing a proportion of the mature rabbits means that $x_{n+1}=(1-p)x_n+y_n$

We could create a recurrence relationship using the above, but we are told that the hunters kill enough rabbits so that in fact $x_{n+1}=1.1x_n$

This has the straightforward solution $x_n=(1.1)^nx_0$

To find out how many need to be killed to achieve this rate of growth, let's look again at the earlier equations.

$z_{n}=x_n \Rightarrow z_{n}=(1.1)^nx_0 $

$y_{n+1}=0.8z_n \Rightarrow y_{n+1}=0.8 \times (1.1)^{n}x_0 \Rightarrow y_{n}=0.8 \times (1.1)^{n-1}x_0$

Since we have both $x_{n+1}=(1-p)x_n+y_n$ and $x_{n+1}=1.1x_n$,

$1.1x_n=(1-p)x_n+y_n \Rightarrow 1.1(1.1)^nx_0=(1-p)(1.1)^nx_0+0.8 \times (1.1)^{n-1}x_0$

$(1.1)^{n+1}x_0=(1-p)(1.1)^nx_0+0.8 \times (1.1)^{n-1}x_0$

$(1.1)^{n+2}x_0=(1-p)(1.1)^{n+1}x_0+0.8 \times (1.1)^{n}x_0$

$(1.1)^2=(1-p)(1.1)+0.8$

$1.21=1.1-1.1p+0.8$

$1.1p=0.69$

$p=0.627$

So you need to kill about 63% of the mature rabbits.